# SqlAlchemy: How can I get multiple ids in single foreign key

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have two tables Person and address. One person can have multiple addresses. When I create relationship between these two tables, I shall be able to get multiple address ids for one person in single foreign key tuple. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about a [one to many relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many),

And as said in a documentation :

> A one to many relationship places a foreign key on the child table
>   referencing the parent. **relationship() is then specified on the
>   parent, as referencing a collection of items represented by the child**:

Basically you should have this :

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    addresses = relationship("Adress")

class Adress(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'adress'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

Adresses attribute of Person contain a collections of all adresses for that person .